# How to get values from different lines via awk or sed?

Tags: awk, sed

My data section is between *START OF TEC MAP* and *END OF TEC MAP*.

I want to get values respectively from

- line of *EPOCH OF CURRENT MAP* (from the first field to six field if possible as date format),
- line of *LAT/LON1/LON2/DLON/H* (from the first field),
- *data* following LAT/LON1/LON2/DLON/H consists of 6 rows or lines.

  - Data starts with **72.5-180.0** and ends with **57.5-180.0**.
  - get the last 3 values from second line and get the first value from third line

[File](ftp://cddis.nasa.gov/gnss/products/ionex/2018/001/codg0010.18i.Z)

File structure as follows:

```
    1                                                      START OF TEC MAP    
 2018     1     1     0     0     0                        EPOCH OF CURRENT MAP
 ...
   70.0-180.0 180.0   5.0 450.0                            LAT/LON1/LON2/DLON/H
  37   44   49   54   56   56   54   51   46   40   34   29   25   22   20   19
  19   19   20   20   20   20   19   18   17   17   17   18   20   21   23   25
  26   26   26   26   25   24   23   22   23   23   25   27   29   31   32   33
  33   33   32   31   29   27   25   23   21   19   17   15   14   13   12   12
  11   11   12   13   16   20   25   31   37
   67.5-180.0 180.0   5.0 450.0                            LAT/LON1/LON2/DLON/H
  45   52   58   63   65   64   61   56   50   43   37   30   25   21   19   18
  19   20   21   22   22   22   21   20   20   20   21   22   24   26   28   29
  30   30   29   27   25   23   21   20   20   21   22   24   27   28   30   30
  30   30   29   28   26   24   22   20   18   16   15   14   13   14   14   14
  15   15   16   18   21   25   31   38   45
  ...
   25                                                      END OF TEC MAP
```

Desired output should:

```
01-Jan-2018 00:00:00 70.0 21 23 25 26
01-Jan-2018 00:00:00 67.5 26 28 29 30
```

I've tried

```
awk '/START OF TEC MAP/,/END OF TEC MAP/' |
awk '/EPOCH OF CURRENT MAP/{print strftime("%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S",mktime($1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6))}' |
$1 == "70.0-180.0" {flag=1}
$1 == "57.5-180.0" {flag=0}
flag && $0 ~ "LAT/LON1/LON2/DLON/H"
awk '$ ~/LAT\/LON1\/LON2\/DLON\/H/ && FNR==2 {print $(NF-2)" "$(NF-1)" "$(NF)}' | awk '$ ~/LAT\/LON1\/LON2\/DLON\/H/ && FNR==3 {print $1}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**script.awk**

```
# skip if wrong part of a file
# - when file is opened, active is false
# - toggle active when START or END line is read
/(START|END) OF TEC MAP/ { active=!active; next }
!active { next }

# extract time and format it
/EPOCH OF CURRENT MAP/ {
    t = strftime("%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S",mktime($1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6))
    next
}

# extract relevant chunks from this section
/LAT\/LON1\/LON2\/DLON\/H/ {
    # pull out first part of first field
    c = $1
    sub(/-.*/,"",c)
    cn = c+0 # treat c as a number

    # only process if within desired range
    if (cn<=72.5 && cn>57.5) {
        # pull out other relevant fields
        v = ""
        getline
        getline
        for (i=2; i>=0; i--) v = v FS $(NF-i)
        getline
        v = v FS $1

        # finished, send to output
        print t,c v
    }
}

# ignore all other lines
```

Use as:

```
gawk -f script.awk data-file
```

Comment: I didn't understand explanation to skip if wrong part of a file and to only process if within desired range. In addition to that, output is not correct truly. I see 7.2 in the fourth field.

Comment: I got it right now expect skip if wrong part of a file . What is "{ active=!active; next }
!active { next }"?

Comment: You specified: "Data starts with 72.5-180.0 and ends with 57.5-180.0." My code assigns `c` from the first part of this and then checks its range. I assumed the suffix is always `-180.0`

Comment: Data file is not different format. Your code works very well but I don' understand why your code prints 7.5. You are right that the suffix is always -180.0.

`01-Oca-2018 00:00:00 72.5 15 16 17 19
01-Oca-2018 00:00:00 70.0 21 23 25 26
01-Oca-2018 00:00:00 67.5 26 28 29 30
01-Oca-2018 00:00:00 65.0 28 29 30 30
01-Oca-2018 00:00:00 62.5 27 28 28 27
01-Oca-2018 00:00:00 60.0 25 25 23 22
01-Oca-2018 00:00:00 7.5 113 110 105 97
01-Oca-2018 01:00:00 72.5 11 14 18 21
01-Oca-2018 01:00:00 70.0 16 20 24 28
01-Oca-2018 01:00:00 67.5 22 26 29 32
01-Oca-2018 01:00:00 65.0 26 30 32 34
`

Comment: sorry, `c` was being treated as a string. Try this fix.